# Можно ли создать диалоговое окно через Qt designer? И как подключить данное окно к коду-логике?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Можно ли создать диалоговое окно в qt designer и подключить его к логике?

Comment: Qt Designer можно встроить любой виджет и вы можете найти на SO ответы на поставленный вами вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Помог комментарий S.Nick:**

Qt Designer можно встроить любой виджет и вы можете найти на SO ответы на поставленный вами вопрос.